# Calling Rest Api from classic ASP

Tags: javascript, rest, asp-classic

I need to call Api using ajax in javascript.
I have used following code to call api

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http://localhost:51870/api/Home/Get',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                debugger;
                alert('error; ' + eval(error));
            }
        });
```

and Code for API is

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {

            List<PieChartValue> lstPieChartValue = new List<PieChartValue>();
            PieChartValue p1 = new PieChartValue
            {
                ColumnName = "text",
                Value = 100
            };
            PieChartValue p2 = new PieChartValue
            {
                ColumnName = "text",
                Value = 200
            };
            lstPieChartValue.Add(p1);
            lstPieChartValue.Add(p2);
            return  new JsonResult(){ Data = lstPieChartValue };
    }
```

I am getting error:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Thanks.